# Nodejs to MSSQL decimal digits issue

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, loopback

I'm working on an application developed using the Loopback framework for Node.js. I need to read data from a csv and save it on my SQL Server DB (I'm using an SQL Server 2014 instance). A column of the csv file contains numbers with 16 decimal digits. I have no problem reading them from the csv file, but when I save them on the DB it changes the last decimal digits. For instance, the first row of the csv has the value "0.0059888523696288" but on the DB i find "0.0059888525865972".

I did a console.log in my javascript code to check the numbers and they're printed correctly, so I'm guessing that the issue happens when the data is read by the DB.

This is the definition of the property mapped in my javascript model:

```
"forecast": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 53,
      "scale": null,
      "mssql": {
        "columnName": "forecast",
        "dataType": "float",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 53,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }
    }
```

I tried changing the definition of the column in the DB table to decimal(18,16) and the one in the model accordingly, I performed the insert again but I got the same result.

Any explainations on this behavior and how to get the correct number on the DB?

edit:

I did some more logging as suggested in the comments, here's an output example:

value read from csv: 0.0045747027551005

value stored in another js variable: 0.0045747027551005

connector output:

```
loopback:connector:mssql SQL:
DECLARE @insertedIds TABLE (id INT)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PLAN]([plan],[period],[forecast]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] into @insertedIds VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)
SELECT id AS insertId from @insertedIds
 Parameters: [137,17,0.0045747027551005] +3ms
```

Value stored on db: 0.0045747025869787

Even after changing the column to decimal (28,16) I got the same output. That's weird.

Comment: >>>"dataType": "float"<<< Don't use FLOAT type in MSSQL

Comment: >>>I tried changing the definition of the column in the DB table to decimal(18,16)<<< When did you change it, after the data was already in the table? You should do it PRIOR to insert, after insert your precision has already gone

Comment: I deleted the data from the DB table, changed the definition and performed the insert again, but I got the same result.

Comment: Possibly you need more logging for research. You logged number which is read from csv. Add logging the value directly before you sending it to model, e.g. use separate variable. Then enable loopback built-in logging for database connector and you'll see what namely is sent to database. Data type mapping is a kind of magic here. Just in case create column as `decimal(28,16)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Float data type in SQL server which is a floating precision number data from -1.79E + 308 to 1.79E + 308. So it is not exact.

You should use Decimal which is a fixed precision and scale numeric data type.

You can specify the number of decimal places also.